# How to use Nginx to run a Spring WebSocket web application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nginx, spring-websocket, linode

Really new to Linode, Nginx, and hosting in general.

I've gotten my website to work using [Linode's](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-deploy-spring-boot-applications-nginx-ubuntu-22-04/) tutorial but I run into trouble when connecting to a web socket and I believe that the issue is in my config file.
I've looked up a [web socket guide](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) but can't adapt it to my needs. What is this configuration missing? Does Nginx need a particular web socket package?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
...

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/my-ws").withSockJS(); 
    }
    
...

}
```

Edit: Here is my new conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        # Proxy HTTP traffic to your backend server
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

        # Enable WebSocket connections
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    # Handle WebSocket traffic
    location /my-ws{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Now, the site loads, but once again an issue when connecting to a web socket.

Browser Console Log:

```
Opening Web Socket...

WebSocket connection to 'ws://my-ip-address/my-ws/561/fu1ytsvi/websocket' failed: 

POST http://my-ip-address/my-ws/561/jb3ojebf/xhr_streaming?t=1677430636249 403

Web Socket Opened...

>>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000

POST http://my-ip-address/my-ws/561/2r0p3rcg/xhr_send?t=1677430636325 403

Whoops! Lost connection to http://my-ip/my-ws
```

Edit 2:
Could it be that I need my server to be HTTPS instead of HTTP?

Answer (score 1):

Changed Web Socket Config from:

```
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/my-ws").withSockJS(); 
    }
```

To:

```
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/my-ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    }
```

I believe this exposes your application to Cross-Site Request Forgery so that would have to be handled.